# Creating table in Oracle using visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g

I have been searching and i could not find it still. Can i know is there any reference that show on how to create a table using c# in visual studio for oracle databse. This means that using visual studio c# to create the table for Oracle insted doing it in the sqldeveloper using SQL statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("user id=You;password=Pass;data source=DB"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("create table YourTableName(ID number)", con))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: sir, you are great, i just it and working. Edi the table name and other things i think i can do already as i got this idea. Sir thanks again. Thanks so much sir.